# android:layout_centerInParent / RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

i have 3 layers, all of them are RelativeLayouts or based on it:

1. content-class
2. overlay-class
3. infobox-layout

In my code i generate an Overlay-object which inflates a infobox-layout. And then i add the Overlayer to the Content-Layer.
My goal is to center (vertical and horizontal) the Info-box  in parent (=overlay) but it doesn't work. It's TOP/LEFT. This is the default behavior, I think.
So here is my code. 
I add the Overlayer to the Content-Layer like this:

```
private void openContent (String url,final ContentLayer content) {
   overlay = new Overlay(context, url);
   content.addView(overlay);
}
```

Here is the Overlayer:

```
public class Overlay extends RelativeLayout {

   // some stuff

   public Overlay(Context context, String url) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.url  = url;
    init(context, null, -1);
   }


   private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    this.setTag(context.getResources().getString(R.string.overlay));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =     new RelativeLayoutout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    this.setLayoutParams(lp);
    this.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    this.getBackground().setAlpha(80);
    isMax = getValueInPrefs();
    inflateLayout();

  }

 private void inflateLayout () {
  String service = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(service);
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.infobox_wrapper, this, true);

 }
// some stuff
}
```

Last but no least, here is my infobox-layout, called infobox_wrapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/epaper_webview_wrapper"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"> <!-- DOESN'T WORK!! -->

   <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:background="@color/grau_actionbar">
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/header_button_close" 
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="X"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/header_button_min_max" 
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="M"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/header_button_close"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/webview_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/grau_actionbar"
       android:layout_below="@id/header">
       <WebView 
         android:id="@+id/epaper_webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am thankful for any help or hint.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot: Hello guys!! :-)

Comment: No one can give me a word of advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:
I deleted android:layout_centerInParent="true" in RelativeLayout(@+id/epaper_webview_wrapper) and set it dynamically in openContent-method:

```
private void openContent (String url,final ContentLayer content) {
   overlay = new Overlay(context, url);
   RelativeLayout epaper_webview_wrapper= (RelativeLayout)overlay.findViewById(R.id.epaper_webview_wrapper);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)epaper_webview_wrapper.getLayoutParams();
   lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
   epaper_webview_wrapper.setLayoutParams(lp);
   content.addView(overlay);
}
```